# Change a constant argument

Tags: c

My problem is I dont know how I can call the function "remove" in search when the function search has an constant argument. I can't change anything with other fuction or arguments either according to question. I want to avoid any duplicate insert elements in search function with calling remove. I get warning all the time because of the constant argument.

```
struct list{
        a
    };



struct list_entr {
    void *b
};


void *search(const list *l, const void *b)
{
    remove(l,b);
}

void remove(list *l, const void *b)

{
    .....
}
```

Comment: You can do a `(list *)l` cast but I'd rather rethink the design: you probably can have argument of type `const list*` in `remove()` as well.

Comment: `const` means the function promises not to change the list. But you want it to change the list. Do you see the problem? Either don't declare it const or don't modify the list.

Comment: *I want to avoid any duplicate insert elements in search function with calling remove.* --> I don't understand what this means.  I also don't understand why `search` needs to call `remove`.  I would expect the other way around ...

Comment: add a function `void removeDuplicate(list * l)` and let _search_ getting a `const list*` and only searching

Comment: yes but search inspects the list and then compare values. When any duplicate finds so it calls remove.

Comment: It's very confusing to the users of the function if it doesn't do what its name suggests. If you want `search` to modify the list, rename it to something more suiting and don't mark the parameter as `const`.

Comment: @bruno I have a header file so I can not add a new function.

Comment: @JuanRodre I do not understand

Comment: Can't I change with pointer? For exampel I have 3 elements (1,a) (2,b) (3,c) in a list number are keys in the list. And I want to add a new element which has same key number like (1,d) so my new list would be  (1,d) (2,b) (3,c).

Comment: sure you can do that in the _insert/add_ function, supposing this function do not get a const list ;-)

Comment: @bruno .I am not suppose to change anything aside from search function

Comment: it is your program, but all of that has non sense, good luck then ^^

Comment: Either you misunderstood your assignment (which seems likely), or whoever gave you that assignment shouldn't teach programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it: `(list*)l`.

But you should ask yourself whether this makes sense. By making the argument `const` you have told the compiler to stop you from changing the list. And now you want to change the list.

If you want to change the list, you should just remove `const`.

Comment: You are definitly right that it doesnt make sense to change a const argument,  Anylway (list*)l works well. Thanks for help